# If value = true then append 1 else 0 in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm not sure if this is feasible, but I figured I'd ask and see if anyone had any bright solutions.

I'm creating a VBA form that people will use to assemble an SQL string: "Tick this box to make this parameter true" kind of stuff.

The obvious way to implement this would be

```
If Checkbox.Value Then
    string = string + "@parameter = 1, "
Else
    string = string + "@parameter = 0, "
End If
```

The annoyance is that this is kind of verbose.  It would be nice if I could do something like this:

```
string = string + "@parameter = " + Checkbox.value + ", "
```

But I'm not sure if that's feasible.  Is it possible?

Comment: true in VBA is -1, so I don't think this would work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered using `IIf`?

```
string = string + "@parameter = " + IIf(Checkbox.value, "1", "0") + ", "
```

You can learn more about the function [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

In VBA, True is -1 and False is 0, which is different than Excel proper (True is 1).

```
string = string + "@parameter = " & CLng(Abs(Checkbox.Value)) & ", "
```

That will convert False to zero and True to positive one.  The Abs probably converts it to a number, so the CLng may be overkill.  But I plead readability.

Answer (score 0):

An even shorter solution would be:

```
string = string + "@parameter = " & -1 * Checkbox.Value & ", "
```