# What's the difference between VBA and Javascript boolean expressions?

Tags: javascript, vba, operators

In JavaScript:

```
alert(True > False) -> true
alert(False > True) -> false
```

Which makes sense as True is 1 and False is 0 ..

But in VBA:

```
Msgbox(4 > 3)        -> true
Msgbox(True > False) -> false
Msgbox(False > True) -> true
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VBA, True is -1 and False is 0. :) And so all equations are right. See the previous question: [If value = true then append 1 else 0 in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061566/if-value-true-then-append-1-else-0-in-vba)

Comment: Thanks! that makes perfect sense :)